# Hide URL path in status bar

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I need to hide url path in status bar in browsers (when you put your mouse under a link, the path of it it's showed in botton of page).

Portion of my code using PHP and HTML:

```
echo "<a href=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?periodo='.$path.'/'.basename($folders[$i])."\" >" . basename($folders[$i]) . "</a><br/>\n";

if(isset($item['diretorio']) && $item['diretorio'] != ''){echo "<tr><td>".$item['vencimento']."</td><td>".$item['baixado']."</td><td>".$item['cliente']."</td><td>".$item['pagamento']."</td><td><a href='".$item['file']."'>Baixar</a></td></tr>";}}?>
```

Comment: Do you mean the address bar?

Comment: By hide, what do you mean exactly? show nothing in the address bar? also, out of curiosity, any good reason to do that?

Comment: URL rewrites don't solve your issue?

Comment: That would be quite handy for phishing websites ;)

Comment: I do not know how URL rewrites will solve it.

Comment: I even a "protector" link may help to "hide" the original link

Comment: This will prevent users to browse another paths in the sistem

Comment: No, it won't prevent that at all.

Answer (score 2):

This was supported back in the days, but it got removed from all browsers.

Sources: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_defaultstatus.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/defaultStatus

Browsers also removed the ability to remove status bar in new windows, for security reasons.